# Expect() not doing the comparison when using BDD

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angular-promise, cucumberjs

I am working with Protractor 5.4.0 and cucumber.

The protractor.conf.js file is:

```
global.expect = require('chai').expect;
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', // This is targetting your local running instance of the selenium webdriver

    specs: [
        '../Features/UI_Tests.feature'
    ],

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome' // You can use any browser you want. On a CI environment you're going to want to use PhantomJS
    },

    framework: 'custom', //We need this line to use the cucumber framework

    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'), // Here it is

    cucumberOpts: {
        //format:  'pretty',
        require: '../Features/step_definitions/my_steps.js', // This is where we'll be writing our actual tests
        // tags: ['@basic'],
        strict: true,
        plugin:"json"
    },
    resultJsonOutputFile:'./testResults.json', //output file path to store the final results in .json format
    params: {
        env: {
            hostname: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000' // Whatever the address of your app is
        }
    }
};
```

I have this scenario defined with some examples:

```
Scenario Outline: dropdown boxes appear and work as expected.
    When go to "URL"
    Then application is running
    When click <box>
    Then <option> is present in <box>

    Examples:
      |box| option|
      |templateSelection| Apparent Energy |
      |templateDeliveryPathSelection| Email |
      |templateLocaleSelection| English |
```

I am using this piece of code to check that text of the dropdown box is the same one as the option column:

```
checkDropdown: function (value,dropdown) {
        var text = element(by.id(dropdown)).getText();
        expect(text).to.eventually.equal(value);
    },
```

It seems to be working properly because the output informs that all the scenarios have passed. However, if we change any of the values in the "option" column to make it fails, the output is the same one, all scenarios pass. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your version of  `chai` is compatible with the `chai-as-promised`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
checkDropdown: function (value,dropdown) {
        var text = element(by.id(dropdown)).getText();
        return expect(text).to.eventually.equal(value);
}
```

It's because you aren't returning the expect. You always have to return a promise in your step definitions. if the function returns undefined it will pass regardless.

I highly recommend using https://github.com/canvaspixels/cucumber-protractor if you're using those two technologies to save tons of boilerplate and effort. You can keep your existing tests and migrate gradually.

There's a demo video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vuYL4nxMXs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but...what is the difference between your code and mine? I think it is the same. Thanks in advance.